# Copy partial data from one SQL DB to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to copy some of the data from one table in one db to another db. So I have a db1 with table1 with some columns say `column1` (unique id), `column2`, `column3` etc. Now I have another db which is a copy of the first one (schema is copied and it will also have some of the data preexisting from db1).

so `db1/table1` has records:

```
column1          column2                   column3
1          12/07/2021 11:60:32         10/03/2021 01:34:00
2          02/02/2021 15:30:32         11/01/2021 15:31:32
3          12/03/2021 17:20:32         13/02/2021 15:30:32
4          12/04/2021 13:40:32         16/08/2021 15:30:34
5          12/06/2021 19:10:32         17/03/2021 15:20:31
```

`db2/table2` has below data:

```
column1          column2                   column3
1                 null                      null
2          02/03/2021 15:30:32              null
5          22/05/2021 15:30:32         12/07/2021 15:30:32
6          22/05/2021 15:30:32         12/07/2021 15:30:32
7          22/05/2021 15:30:32         12/07/2021 15:30:32
```

I would like to copy data from `db1/table1` to `db2/table2` except for those which are not present in `db2/table2` (based on the `column1` used as identifier). So in this example, records with `column1` value 3 and 4 should not be copied into db2/table2.

I am able to get it to work if all records are present in `db2/table2` but when the records are missing it runs into error saying no records exist. Sorry if its a trivial one, I am not too good with SQL at all and trying to figure out a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Update your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to copy the rows that *don't* exist in `table2`, then you would use `not exists`:

```
insert into db2.table2 (col1, col2, col3)
    select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
    from db1.table1 t1
    where not exists (select 1 from db2.table2 t2 where t2.col1 = t1.col1);
```

The above seems sensible.  But if you want to *update* the values in `table2` only for matches, then use `update` with a `join`:

```
update t2
    set t2.col2 = t1.col2,
        t2.col3 = t1.col3
    from table2 t2 join
         table1 t1
         on t2.col1 = t1.col1;
```